# copy date variable without formula from excel in python

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

I have 250 excel files, each has a formula in the date variable. now I am trying to merge the 250 files into single file in python, but I am getting the date as 1899-02-05 where the dataset ranges from 2000 to 2020.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for ind in list2.index:
    wb = load_workbook(list1[0][ind], data_only=True)
    ws = wb.active
    ws.delete_rows(0,1)
    data = ws.values
    columns = next(data)[0:]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    print(ind)
    df2 = df2.append(df)
```

the above code is working but I am getting the same wrong date in each row.

Comment: I don't have much experience with excel files but aren't you supposed to use `pd.read_excel('path/to/excel')` on each file, then `pd.to_excel` to write it out? Maybe this guide [here](https://pythoninoffice.com/merge-multiple-excel-files-in-python/) could help, sorry I can't help more

Comment: how does the "wrong dates" look like (as compared to the original value) ?